# If we are given closure , left & right identity and left & right inverse. Can we prove this forms a group (or you can say implies associativity)?

Tags: group-theory

As we know closure, associativity, left identity and left inverse are enough conditions for a group.

If we are given closure , left & right identity and left & right inverse. Can we prove this forms a group (or you can say implies associativity)?

I have tried my best to prove or disprove it. Counterexample, proof or links - all are welcome.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps this wikipedia page will help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Loops

Comment: The nonzero octonions under multiplication are a standard example of a set with an operation that has inverses and an identity, but is neither associative nor commutative (though it is power associative, which not all loops are).

Comment: Somehow related to this. The following should be each a sufficient condition such that a set endowed with an *associative* composition law is a group (and the like ones by replacing "left" with "right"):

1) left unit ∧ left inverse elements;
2) left unit ∧ right inverse elements ∧ right cancellation.

Instead, the following are *not* sufficient to the aim:

a) left unit ∧ right inverse elements;
b) left cancellation ∧ right cancellation (unless the set is finite! In that case, b) is sufficient as well).